# J2EE Application - Persistence technology

Tags: java, xml, types, persistence, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm always challenging an architecture of "my perfect" web platform.
I was testing some frameworks around Java technologies, and I bumped into Hybris. I tested the model architecture:

- configuration of new item types in XML configuration file (properties with modifiers, and relations with other types)
- enhancement of existing items of the framework with new properties and relations
- Persistence into several datasource (HSQL, SQL, ...)
- Generate Model java class based on configured items

Do somebody know a good equivalent of this kind of persistence layer?

Sincerely,

Comment: So you want something like the persistence layer of Hybris, but standalone?

Comment: Yes something like hybris does, if it exists in standalone/free ?